# keytool is not recognized as an internal/external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: android, keytool, signing, android-keystore

When i use a command `keytool -genkey -v -keystore MY-RELEASE-KEY.keystore -alias MY_ALIAS_NAME -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000`

I get error like this `'keytool' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

What can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to navigate to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk_version\bin` and execute the request there

Comment: not working `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_71\bin"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: did you just execute the path ? by navigate i mean open cmd at that path and execute your command line there